# exp(b) negative binomial regression

Tags: r, interpretation, negative-binomial-distribution

I am currently running a negative binomial regression, the log of expected counts is not as easy to understand, interpret.
So I am wondering if I can, just like in logistic regression take the exp(b), to make the coefficients more interpretable.
And if so, how would that be like ?
For exmaple in a logistic regression if I have the log odds, I did the following:

`(exp(model$coefficients)-1)*100`

EDIT:
the way I interpret the coefficients, ß, in a logistic regression is the following, lets say in my output, ß2 has the following value: 0.223, that means if x2 increases by one unit, then the log odds of y increase by 0.223, or I can just do the following transformation: (exp(0.223)-1)*100 = 24.98, this would mean that if x2 increases by one unit, the odds of y happening increases by 24.98 %. However what I need is a transformation for a negative binomial regression –

EDIT2:
Lets say in my negative binomial regression output ß2 has the following coefficient: 0.040555,
I know that I can interpret it as following: if x2 increases by one unit, then the difference in the logs of expected count for y increases by 0.04055.

But I am curious how to interpret it if I take exp(0.040555)

I am very grateful for any help

Comment: How would you do this in logistic regression?

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: You wrote that you want to do something “just like in logistic regression”, so what would you do in a logistic regression?

Comment: I took the exp(log(odds)), you can see the code in my question

Comment: That does not invert the logistic link function.

Comment: so does that mean, I am not able to make the coefficients more interpretable ?

Comment: It seems that you think you understand how to do this in a logistic regression. Let’s start there. How would you make logistic regression coefficients more interpretable, and what is the interpretation? It might be worth editing this information into your original question, as the explanation might exceed what is available in comments. (I also find it easier to write math in regular posts than comments, since there is a preview of my TeX.)

Comment: Alright then...So the way I interpret the coefficients, ß, in a logistic regression is the following, lets say in my output, ß2 has the following value: 0.223, that means if x2 increases by one unit, then the log odds of y increase by 0.223, or I can just do the following transformation: (exp(0.223)-1)*100 = 24.98, this would mean that if x2 increases by one unit, the chance of y happening increases by 24.98 %. However what I need is a transformation for a negative binomial regression

Comment: It will help to use technical terminology, and “chance” is not technical terminology. Do you mean probability? Odds? Those are not synonymous in this kind of technical setting (and yes, that they are synonymous colloquially makes the communication difficult).

Comment: yes that what I mean, I mean odds which I wrongly called chance

Comment: so what can I do ?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I have a count variable y, and I need to run a negative binomial regression. But like I said I finde it difficult to interpret the logs of expected counts, so I wanted to use exp instead to make it easier, but I am not sure if it works